# ErrorException in cellmap using DomPDF

Tags: laravel-5, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF usin DomPDF, I'm working on Laravel 5.0, It was working a while ago but then when I added the table I get this error:

```
ErrorException in cellmap.cls.php line 676:
Undefined offset: 688
```

The HTML code that I'm trying to include is this, there's all the HTML of the view:

```
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section >
            <h1>
                Reporte Academico
                <small>Prof. Malika VonRueden MD</small>
                <small class="pull-right small">Creado: 2015-12-04</small>
            </h1>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- INICIO DETALLE-->
                <section class="invoice">
                    <!-- title row -->
                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- info row -->
                    <div class="row invoice-info">
                        <!-- /.col -->
                        <!-- Datos Perfil-->

                        <section class="invoice">
                            <!-- title row -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <h2 class="page-header">Prof. Malika VonRueden MD
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- info row -->
                            <div class="row invoice-info">

                                <!-- Datos Perfil-->

                                <div class="col-md-9 invoice-col">
                                    <strong>Apellidos:</strong>
                                    <b>Monahan</b>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Nombres:</strong>
                                    <label>Prof. Malika VonRueden MD</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Edad:</strong>
                                    <label>18</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Profesion:</strong>
                                    <label>illum</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Documento de Identidad:</strong>
                                    <label>CED 850574611</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Telefono:</strong>
                                    <label>863)-58123956</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Telefono movil:</strong>
                                    <label>733-52524688</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Correo electronico:</strong>
                                    <a href="mailto:#">Althea.Labadie@Brown.info</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <strong>Direccion de residencia:</strong>
                                    <address>38583 Robel Mall
New Morganstad, OH 85126.Barrio Watersmouth</address>
                                    <br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
                                    <address>
                                        <img src="http://localhost/passport/passport/public/adminlte/dist/imgAvatar/avatar.png" class="img-circle">
                                    </address>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col -->
                                <!-- Fin Datos Perfil -->

                                <div class="col-md-10" style="margin:auto;float:none">
                                    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Observaciones</h2>

                                    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="bg-primary">Id</th>
                                            <th class="bg-primary">Fecha</th>
                                            <th class="bg-primary">Responsable</th>
                                            <th class="bg-primary">Tipo</th>
                                            <th class="bg-primary">Detalle</th>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 13:58:48</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 16:00:22</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 17:10:13</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>4</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 17:10:25</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>5</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 17:10:40</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>6</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:38:26</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>7</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:39:48</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>8</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:40:35</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>9</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:49:55</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>10</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:51:12</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>11</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:55:30</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 19:55:47</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>13</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 21:19:14</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td>14</td>
                                            <td>2015-12-02 21:34:26</td>
                                            <td>Prof. Conrad Hermann Schultz</td>
                                            <td>S</td>
                                            <td>Datos actualizados</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->
                        </section>
                        <!-- Fin Datos Perfil -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </section>
                <!-- /.content -->
                <!-- FIN DETALLE-->
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <footer class="main-footer" style="margin-left:0px">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
            <b>Reporte creado en</b> 2015-12-04
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2015 <a href="http://almsaeedstudio.com">Passport</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

for future visitors, the problem is with bootstrap that doesn't work well with *DomPDF*, for that the recomendation is to use [this library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)
The same for users of *Foundation*

Comment: dompdf *can* process bootstrap-styled documents, though the results won't necessarily look like you expect. You'll always get better results from a headless browser like wkhtmltopdf or PhantomJS.

Comment: FYI, I was able to process your document without any errors. Even after adding a reference to bootstrap. That being said, an undefined offset is usually a warning not a fatal error. You might want to tweak your error reporting.